# Possible to get ant's javah commandline?

Tags: java, ant, javah

Ant task:

```
<target name="regenerateJNIHeader" description="Re-generates the JNI header">
    <echo message="Re-generating JNI header" />
    <attrib readonly="false">
        <fileset dir="." includes="**/MyAPI*.h"/>
    </attrib>
    <javah class="com.MyAPI" force="yes" verbose="yes"/>
</target>
```

Problem is, I made a change (added a method) to MyAPI, but, despite clearing the header file and compiled class files, when I run this task, my new method is not added.  If I run `javah com.MyAPI`, it works properly.

Possible to see the commandline for ant tasks as it executes them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue.  Not quite what I was asking, but I found the info I needed.

I set the ant commandline to have `-v` (verbose), which printed out much more info.  In the output, I saw the classpath, which I had not set.  Added the `classpath` attribute to the javah task and set it to `"."` and now the generated header contains my new method.

I am surmising that, despite not explicitly mentioning it in the classpath (in the javah task verbose output), it must have been looking for the specified class in a jar which I'd placed in `$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/ext`.